# Hazelcast topic message expiry

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, hazelcast

Can anyone share some notes on message expiration policy in Hazelcast ITopic? I could not find any documentation on that.

Basically I am designing a peer-to-peer file sharing subsystem leveraging Hazelcast publish-subscribe. I would want to make sure that my message chunks (which are basically file chunks) get expired after the message has been consumed. I do have a handshake mechanism in place, to get notified on receipt completion, however, not being able to 'clear' the topic someway.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "clearing the topic"? After the message is consumed, it will not appear on the same node again.

Hazelcast itself does not have expiry for topic built-in as the system is a fire and forget implementation. Even on ReliableTopic you would have to build an envelope containing a timestamp. Anyhow I guess I'm not sure what you really mean by "expiry" in your usecase.

Comment: So my question should have been, after the message is consumed, is it still present in any distributed data structure? I thought if ITopic uses some IMap internally to subscribe, then will there be any concept of message expiry? However, from your answer it seems that it does not use an IMap.

Comment: no ITopic is fire and forget. It is not redelivered, it is not stored, it is just sent :) So every subscriber being subscribed and reachable at the time of message send will retrieve it at most once.
It is different for IReliableTopic though which is based on a RingBuffer. For the ringbuffer every client / member knows its own last-read position and won't re-read the same element, anyhow other consumers are able to read it. There is no deliver-once system in place beside using a distributed queue.